# Why is event.stopPropagation not cancelling $('html').click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an input field which has a focusout event on it. I also have a click event set on $('html') which transfers focus to a different input field. I wrote a click handler for my input field and put in event.stopPropagation(); but it doesn't seem to be working. What am I missing? What does $('html') refer to? My code:

```
p.replaceWith(
    "<input class='memoryEditField' type='text' value=" + p.text() + ">"
  );
var inputField = $(".memoryEditField");
  inputField
  .on("click", function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
  })
  .on("focusout", editFieldLostFocus)
  .on("keyup", editFieldKeyPressed);
```

The other input field:

```
$("html").on("touchstart", function() {
    MQInput.focus();
});
$("html").on("click", function() {
    MQInput.focus();
});
```

Comment: can u please post your html part?

Comment: does anything show in the console before you click on the input field?

Comment: @KalaiselvanA A lot of html is being generated through js, do you want to see anything specifically?

Comment: @LioraHaydont My click event runs fine but then focus is shifted to the other MQInput

Comment: Yah!, which is related to this post

Comment: what is MQInput means?

Comment: Maybe depending your clicked element (`label` with `for` attribute e.g), this is default behaviour. To test, try to prevent default behaviour too, using e.g `return false;` instead of `event.stopPropagation();`

Comment: @KalaiselvanA Added html. It just refers to another input field through a js class

Comment: @A.Wolff return false isn't working either. Can you tell me what is 'html' here? Someone else wrote this line and I am having trouble understanding why use 'html' instead of 'document'?

Comment: @Tehreem BUT are you sure the click handler is bound? It looks like dynamic element

Comment: @A.Wolff if i give it a console.log statement, it prints when it is clicked

Comment: I'm unable to replicate your issue

Comment: try `$(document).on('click' , inputField , function(event){ event.stopPropagation(); }).on('focusout' , inputField , editFieldLostFocus).on('keyup' , inputField , editFieldKeyPressed);`   .. maybe you need [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements) after using `.replaceWith()`

Comment: @A.Wolff I have huge files of code and I didn't write most of it.. Probably something else messing with it. Thanks though

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef no luck

Comment: @Tehreem try to update jquery version to latest. also can You provide link to live example of Your code? I want to debug it

Answer (score 0):

Please provide all of code (what is `p` in Your code? Also `editFieldLostFocus`, `editFieldKeyPressed`).

I think You're missing something in methods `editFieldLostFocus`, `editFieldKeyPressed` and it makes illusion that `stopPropogation` does no work

In fact it works as expected:

```js
$(function() {
  $('p').each(function() {
    var p = $(this);
    p.replaceWith(
      '<input class="memoryEditField" type="text" value="' + p.text() + '">'
    );
  });
  
  function editFieldLostFocus() {
    console.log('call editFieldLostFocus');
  }
  
  function editFieldKeyPressed() {
    console.log('call editFieldKeyPressed');
  }
  
  var inputFields = $(".memoryEditField");
  inputFields
    .on("click", function(event) {
      event.stopPropagation();
      console.log('memoryEditField clicked');
    })
    .on("focusout", editFieldLostFocus)
    .on("keyup", editFieldKeyPressed);
    
  $("html").on("touchstart", function() {
    console.log('MQInput.focus');
    //MQInput.focus();
  });
  $("html").on("click", function() {
    console.log('MQInput.focus');
    //MQInput.focus();
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>FIELD 1</p><br/>
<p>FIELD 2</p><br/>
```

Comment: I removed editFieldLostFocus and editFieldKeyPressed and ti still doesn't work. And I can't post the whole file here it's a bunch of files with 500+ lines each. Thanks though

Comment: is it hosted somewhere?

Comment: Not my repo. Can't share that either. I think I am going to have to ask the guy who wrote the MQInput thing to remove it. Everything was working fine before that

Comment: I don't think it's about MQInput. I only can suspect jquery version that registers click on field somewhat different or some other element that covering input element.